# How to include audio file in PDF

Tags: pdf, include, audio

How do I include audio file, or should I say, link to audio file in PDF?

1. Audio should be playable "from
   PDF directly", without opening
   any additional window.
2. Is it possible to attach audios to PDF
       then so I can manipulate only with
       that file, without being bothered
       with copying folders where those
       audio files would reside?

I saw that 1. is definitely doable (but don't know how) and I'm interested if second one is also possible (while compiling `.tex` file) since I know that some files (like graphs and tables) can be attached in PDF, but after it's generated.

[image] Button for playing audio from document that uses this trick.

Comment: Keep in mind that most methods for embedding audio/video are not implemented in many PDF readers.  It may very likely be the case that the audio link will only work in Adobe Acrobat/Reader.

Comment: I am reminded of Knuth's recent talk: http://river-valley.tv/tug-2010/an-earthshaking-announcement

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though suggested packages are very good, after quite of looking around, I've found `attachfile` the best for my purpose.

Comment: @user1996 I up voted your self proposed solution. I was not aware of attach file before. Could you describe how does it work? Do you have to unpack PDF file before you play? I see pdftk listed as one way to do that but that is pdf manipulator not a viewer. Does your solution suffer from the same problem as movie15 it depends on Acroread.

Answer (score 13):

The now obsolete [movie15](https://ctan.org/pkg/movie15) package used to be a good choice. This package has been superseded by the [media9](https://ctan.org/pkg/media9) package. The manuals provide a variety of examples.

Comment: That's right!!! The movie15 package is in my opinion the best. You can include movie and audio files and 3D models also.

Comment: The docs for that package say it is obsolete and suggest [`media9`](http://ctan.org/pkg/media9).

Comment: who answered could update the answer

Answer (score 6):

Try the `multimedia` package, which is part of the `beamer` distribution.  It's documented in Section 14.2 of the beamer 2.10 manual, and it does provide the ability to embed sound files into the pdf.  Not all sound formats are supported, and I'm sure not all pdf viewers can play sounds natively.  So YMMV.