# Embed HTML in LaTeX document

Tags: pdf, html, audio

Is it possible to run HTML code in a Latex document? Probably not since I never seen it.

Soundcloud have an miniplayer that you can embed in your homepage to give the reader the possibility to play a soundtrack while reading. I want to do this in a LaTeX document.

Is it possible? Just wanted to check.

Comment: You want a Soundcloud player embedded in your final PDF file? LaTeX is definitely not the best tool for that (if there's any) I fear.

Comment: Sort of related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7502/how-to-include-audio-file-in-pdf

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Sounds like something [`hyperref`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/hyperref)/[`multimedia`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/multimedia)/[`media9`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/media9) *might* be able to do.

Comment: @You: ... in ascending order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**
If the soundcloud player provides a *Download* button for the MP3 file (see e. g. https://soundcloud.com/explore) , the sound can be played back in `APlayer.swf` from the `media9` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\noindent\includemedia[
  transparent,
  flashvars={
     source=https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/123576194/download?client_id=b45b1aa10f1ac2941910a7f0d10f8e28
    &autoPlay=true
  }
]{\framebox[\linewidth]{\strut}}{APlayer.swf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It did not work unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, but sounds available for download can be played in the audio player from the `media9` package. See the edit.