# On some specific slides I want to either show an icon (bell) or ring it once when I reach that slide in the presentation

Tags: beamer

The icon (bell) OR the bell-sound is intended to remind me to engage the class in a discussion, or ask a hidden question to elicit discussion!

Comment: For the icons, try  [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/259006/11604) and add to the example   `\faBell` or  `\faBellO`.

Comment: For the sound, take a look at this question: [How to include audio file in PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7502/how-to-include-audio-file-in-pdf)